# Javascript in wordpress post - apostrophes renedering issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to add post to wordpress using external script. The post contains javascript section, which is an iframe for displaying movies. I know wordpress splits as deafault  tags, so I'm using a special plugin to do that. Everything works ok on my localhost and the posts are displayed corerectly(with the iframe). However on the server I got an issue. The iframe is not displayed and I figured out that the problem is in renedering post's content by wordpress. Here are two versions of the source file, which better ilustrate my problem.

Source file from my localhost, which works ok:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
HDplayer_Iframe.load({ 
'id' : 'hdplayer-iframe', 
'referrer' : '5139b992d1cb84c7130b0537586d3e8e737e2f33==', 
'title' : 'Wyścig', 
'image' : 'http://1.fwcdn.pl/po/82/62/628262/7577202.6.jpg?l=1382963342000', 
'size' : 'small', 
'style' : 'playful-dark', 
'fb' : 1 
}); 
</script>
```

Source file from webserver:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
HDplayer_Iframe.load({ 
‚id’ : ‚hdplayer-iframe', 
‚referrer’ : '5139b992d1cb84c7130b0537586d3e8e737e2f33==', 
‚title’ : ‚Wyścig', 
‚image’ : ‚http://1.fwcdn.pl/po/82/62/628262/7577202.6.jpg?l=1382963342000', 
‚size’ : ‚small', 
‚style’ : ‚playful-dark', 
‚fb’ : 1 
}); 
</script>
```

Looks like apostrophes are rendered to these "‚ ’" symbols. Any help and explanation highly appreciated!

Comment: Kindly recheck as I am getting no such issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that there some issue on that particular wordpress version. After clean installation everything works fine. Thanks to everyone who was racking his brain on this problem;)